# how to get the exact status code of the response after doing model.save in backbone js

Tags: node.js, express, backbone.js, model, save

From the front end, using backbone js I am doing:

```
this.model.save()
        .success(function (data) {
          console.log("The response is " + JSON.stringify(data));
        })
        .error(function (error) {
          console.log("The response is " + JSON.stringify(error));
        })
```

From the server side, the mocked response is

```
res.status(400).send({message: "Bad request"})
```

So, I am being able to print the object that is being sent in the **res.send** method for both 2XX and non-2XX status. 
However, I also want to **print the exact status** (the one being sent in the **res.status** from the server). Could someone please throw some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone Ajax requests use jQuery (http://backbonejs.org/#Sync), and your `success` handler is passed through. Under `jqXHR.done` (`success` is deprecated but has the same signature) in the [jQuery.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you'll see there's 3 parameters.

What you are looking for is:

```
.success(function (data, statusText, xhr) {
  console.log("The response status code is " + xhr.status);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mikeapr4. However, I could only select your answer as the correct one because StackOverflow is not even allowing me to upvote your answer (less than 15 reputations).